# Stop waiting for tasks in a For Each loop

Tags: workflow, tasks

I'm trying to create a workflow that loops through a column of Reviewers. The number of reviewers can vary, which is why I'm using a For Each that breaks down the multiple users entered and loops for each of them in the collection.

The issue I've run into is that the workflow will then pause until the user completes their task. The way I envisioned this workflow working was that all the users get their tasks, and then if any take over, say, a week, it auto-ends their tasks.

Of course then I need some way to make the workflow stop before continuing past the For Each loop, but that's a whole other headache.

One workaround I tried was using a separate Workflow for the task, but this has it's own issues since you can't run multiple instances of the same workflow on the same List item.

I can't figure out a way to make this work without making each of the tasks sequential, which is what I wanted to avoid. Of course, it may be that what I want just isn't possible.

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In General, if you don't want the workflow actions to wait for the task completion in SharePoint designer workflow,

1. go to the **task options**
2. uncheck **wait for the task completion** check box
3. then click OK

by doing that, the workflow actions will continue without waiting for the users to complete their tasks.

[image]